# Why can't puppet find my defined resource?

Tags: puppet

I have a defined resource in /etc/puppet/modules/autofs/manifests/mount.pp (from the pdx-cat/autofs module at https://forge.puppetlabs.com/pdxcat/autofs).

I have a module in /etc/puppet/modules/sheffield/manifests/autofs/net.pp which is trying to use the autofs::mount defined type.

```
class sheffield::autofs::net {
  include ::autofs

  autofs::mount { '/net':
    map     => '',
    options => '-hosts',
  }
}
```

But when the client attempts to grab the catalog, I get the following error;

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with error ArgumentError: Invalid resource type autofs::mount at /etc/puppet/modules/sheffield/manifests/autofs/net.pp:7 on node rhel6test.shef.ac.uk
```

Any ideas? I thought maybe it was a problem with not being autoload the type as it has the same name (autofs) as a subclass in sheffield::autofs, so I tried renaming to sheffield::auto-fs and it made no difference.

I tried copying the mount.pp from /etc/puppet/autofs/manifests into /etc/puppet/sheffield/manifests/autofs/ and it did find the resource type, but didn't work because of a load of other missing dependencies in mount.pp (and obviously, that's not a nice solution to the problem).

Comment: What version of Puppet are you running? Your example works fine for me on 3.1.0.

Comment: It's not having a problem with the manifest you've provided, it's not finding a defined type at `autofs::mount`.  Can you show us what that defined type (and its related file structure) looks like?  This seems like a relative name lookup problem in 2.7 - unfortunately, the solution to that would be to either upgrade to 3 or change the name collision; are you certain there was no change in behavior under a different name?

Comment: Did you also rename the directory `/etc/puppet/modules/sheffield/manifests/autofs/`to `auto-fs` when you tried renaming `sheffield::autofs`?

Answer (score 1):

Since `include ::autofs` gives no error, you should be able to use the same `::` prefix on the define:

```
class sheffield::autofs::net {
  ::autofs::mount { '/net':
    ...
  }
}
```

If it doesn't work, there is probably an error in modulepath or other related settings.

`include ::autofs` line is actually not needed. The mount-define includes all necessary classes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem: custom resource defined, classes clearly there, listed in Foreman.

For me, the problem turned out to be that the `metadata.json` was badly formed, and missing the "source" attribute. Worth checking if nothing else seems to solve the issue!